# How to ignore bootstrap codes from main css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**PROBLEM:** I am having problems in my bootstrap imports that seems to be affecting my link logo and social icon border. If i remove the link for the bootstrap, the logo and icon borders will work fine. However, I need the bootstrap tag for the gallery. Can someone help me fix this?

[this is the code with errors](https://codepen.io/UmaruHime/pen/NLZrWN)

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
```

This is the source of error (Specifically the code above) :

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Sabreen's Seafood Market &amp; Restaurant</title>
    <link href="css/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/seafood-favicon.png"/>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
</head>
```

This is my current output with the link for the bootstrap enabled.You could see that the logo and social box is not properly placed.
[image]

This is what it looks like when i commented the bootstrap link. You can see that the logo and social border works fine, but the gallery does not.
[image]

Is there anyway for me to fix both?

**HERE IS THE HTML CODE**

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Sabreen's Seafood Market &amp; Restaurant</title>
    <link href="css/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/seafood-favicon.png"/>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
</head>
<body>
    <a name="home">
<!--- Start Navigation -->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script> <!--- For Navigation -->

        <!---ADD NAVIGATION HERE-->
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.php"><img src="images/seafoodLogo.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-outer">
            <div class="nav-wrap">
                <nav class="navigation">

                    <div class='nav' nav-menu-style="yoga">
                        <ul class="nav-menu">
                            <li> <a href="explore.php">EXPLORE</a></li>
                            <li> <a href="menu.php">MENU</a></li>
                            <li> <a href="#gallery">GALLERY</a></li>
                            <li> <a href="reservation.php">RESERVATION</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>


    <div class="nav-clear"></div>
<!--- End Navigation -->
    <div class="clearfix"></div>

<!-- Start of Content -->
<h1> Check out some of our Suggested Paluto!</h1>
<section class="paluto">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="box-paluto">
            <div class="imgBox-paluto">
              <img src="images/menu/crabs1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="content-paluto">
              <h3>Sweet Chili Crab</h3>
              <p>Considered as one of our year-round staples, our bright and bold #ChiliCrab packs a lot of flavor and heat! If you prefer to have it mildly spiced, our kitchen team is flexible with all types and tastes and preference.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="box-paluto">
            <div class="imgBox-paluto">
              <img src="images/menu/crabs2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="content-paluto">
              <h3>Grilled Crab</h3>
              <p>Our take on #GrilledCrab is deliciously simple and oozing with smoky flavor. Plus it's meaty and guaranteed fresh! Contact us on our Facebook fan page for booking and inquiries.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="box-paluto">
            <div class="imgBox-paluto">
              <img src="images/menu/crabs3.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="content-paluto">
              <h3>Sweet Chili Crab with Black Pepper</h3>
              <p>Thankfully, crabs are always at full swing and piled high in our #seafoodrestaurant! Roll up your sleeves and get ready to indulge our #chilicrab that's deliciously drenched with garlic and herbs. We're open 'til 10:30 pm so it's never too late to satisfy your cravings for crustaceans!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- End of Content -->
<div class="clearfix"></div>

<footer>
    <center>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/seafoodmarketandrestaurant/" target="_blank" title="Follow us on Facebook" class="fa fa-facebook" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"></a></center>
    <p> &copy 2018 SABREEN'S SEAFOOD MARKET &amp; RESTAURANT ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</p>
</footer>
</body>
```

**HERE IS THE CSS CODE FOR MY NAV.CSS AND STYLES.CSS**

```
/*styles.css*/

/*---Body Font--*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hindi);
/*---Heading Font--*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nobile);
/*---Social Font--*/
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
/*---Menu Gallery Font--*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,700');

* {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #fffdf9;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 175%;
    color: #494949;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    padding: 3% 0;
}
h2 {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 150%;
    color: #494949;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    padding: 3% 0;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #494949;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1%;
}

p {
    padding: 2%;
    color: #4A4444;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 125%;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: auto;
}
#banner-wrapper {
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*---Start Image Slider Style--*/
.slider {
    width: 100%;
}
.slider1 img {
    min-width: 100%;
}
.slider .bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a {
    outline: 0 none;
    position: absolute;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    top: 40%;
    height: 71px;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: all 0.7s;
}
.slider .bx-wrapper:hover .bx-controls-direction a{
    z-index: 5;
}
.slider .bx-wrapper .bx-prev {
    background: #000 url("img/left-arrow-white.png") no-repeat 8px 13px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
.slider .bx-wrapper .bx-prev:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
.slider .bx-wrapper .bx-next {
    background: #000 url("img/right-arrow-white.png") no-repeat 10px 12px;
    right: 0px;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
.slider .bx-wrapper .bx-next:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
/*---End Image Slider Style--*/
.reservation {
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.reservation p {
    width: 70%;
    text-align: center;
}
.one-half {
    width: 44%;
    float: left;
    margin: 2% 0 3% 4%;
    text-align: center;
}
.one-third {
    width: 28%;
    float: left;
    margin: 2% 0 3% 4%;
    text-align: center;
}
.left-col {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    margin: 4% 0 4% 4%;
}
.sidebar {
    width: 26%;
    float: right;
    margin: 4% 4%;
}
.sidebar img {
    opacity: 1;
}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
/*---Start Parallax Section--*/
.parallax-1 {
    background: url("../images/parallaxBG.jpg") fixed 100%;
    text-align: center;
    max-height: 300px
}   
.parallax-inner {
    padding-top: 90px;
    padding-bottom: 300px;
}
.parallax-2 {
    background: url("https://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/black-pattern.jpg") repeat fixed 100%;
    text-align: center;
}   
.parallax-inner h3, .parallax-inner p{
    color: #F1F1F1;
}
/*---End Parallax Section--*/

/*Start of Menu Gallery Section*/
section.paluto {
  padding: 50px 0 0 ;
}

.box-paluto {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 280px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  transition: .5s;
}

.box-paluto:hover {
  transform: translateY(-30px);


}

.box-paluto .imgBox-paluto {
  position: relative;
}
.box-paluto .imgBox-paluto img {
  transition: .5s;
  width: 100%;
}
.box-paluto:hover .imgBox-paluto img {
  opacity: .5;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}
.box-paluto .content-paluto{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing; border-box;
  transition: .5s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.box-paluto:hover .content-paluto{
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: 0;
}
.box-paluto .content-paluto h3{
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.box-paluto .content-paluto p{
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .box-paluto{
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
  .box-paluto{
    max-height: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 15px 0;
  }
}
/*End of Menu Gallery Section*/

/*Start of Social*/
.fa {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 2px;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 4px solid #d3d3d3;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    background: #fff;
}
.fa:hover {
    -webkit-animation: expand 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: expand 0.5s ease-in-out;
    animation: expand 0.5s ease-in-out;
    color: #fff;
}
@keyframes expand {
    33% { transform: scale(1.1); }
    66% { transform: scale(0.9); }
    100% { transform: scale(1.0); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes expand {
    33% { transform: scale(1.1); }
    66% { transform: scale(0.9); }
    100% { transform: scale(1.0); }
}
@-moz-keyframes expand {
    33% { transform: scale(1.1); }
    66% { transform: scale(0.9); }
    100% { transform: scale(1.0); }
}
.fa-facebook {
    color: #3B5998;
}
.fa-facebook:hover {
    background: #3B5998;
}
/*End of Social*/
/*---Start Footer--*/
footer {
    background: #fffdf9;
    opacity: 0.9;
    width: 100%;
    /*margin-top: 5%;*/
    padding: 1% 0;
    overflow: auto;

}
footer p{
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #d0d5de, #001947 40%, #001947 60%, #d0d5de 100%);
    padding: 7px 0;
}
iframe {
    width: 60%;
    height: 400px;
}

/*---Start Media Queries--*/
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .slider .bx-wrapper .bx-controls {
        display: none;
    }
    .parallax-inner {
        display: none;
    }
    .one-third {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 4% 0;
    }
    .one-half {
        display: none;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 125%;
    }
    .left-col {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 0 3% 0;
    }
    .sidebar {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .sidebar img {
        max-width: 75%;
        height: auto;
    }
    h3 {
        padding-top: 3%;
    }
    .social-container {
        display: block;
    }
    footer{
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
    .reservation p {
        margin-top: 155px;
        width: 80%;
    }
    iframe {
        width: 80%;
        height: 400px;
    }


}

/*nav.css*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial);
/*--- Nav Font --*/
/*--- Start Navigation Style --*/
.nav-outer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 67px;
    background: #fffdf9;
    position: fixed !important;
    z-index: 1;
}
.nav-wrap {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
nav {
    margin-top: 0;
    background: #fffdf9;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
.nav ul {
    overflow:hidden;
    list-style:none;
}
.nav-button:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.navigation {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.nav a {
    color: #494949;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
}
body .nav .nav-menu li a {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding:15px 20px;
    color: #494949;
    font-size: 19px;
}
.nav.yoga .nav-menu li.active a {
    color: #494949;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.nav.yoga .nav-menu li a:hover {
    color: #494949;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.nav.yoga .nav-toggled {
    min-height:36px;
    border-radius:6px;
    margin-top: -7px;
}
.nav.yoga .nav-toggled-controls {
    display:block;
    height:40px;
    text-align:left;
    position:relative;
}
.nav.yoga .nav-toggled-title {
    position:relative;
    top:9px;
    left:15px;
    font-size:16px;
}
.nav.yoga .nav-button {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    right:15px;
    top:8px;
    background: #0a0c42;
}
.nav.yoga .nav-button span {
    display:block;
    margin-top:4px;
    height:2px;
    background: #0a0c42;
    width:24px;
}
.nav-toggled-controls{
    border-bottom: 0px solid #0a0c42;
}
.nav.yoga .nav-toggled ul li a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #505E67;
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px 0px 10px 15px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.nav.yoga .nav-toggled ul li ul a {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: none;
}
.nav.yoga .nav-toggled ul li.active a {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    color: #505E67;
}
.nav.yoga .nav-toggled ul li a:hover {
    background: #F5F5F5;
    color: #505E67;
}
.nav.yoga .nav-toggled ul li {
    position: relative;
}
.toggle-sm:after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
.toggle-sm:after {
    content: '+';
    cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle-sm.open:after {
    content: '-';
    cursor: pointer;
}
.nav .nav-menu {
    text-align: center;
    overflow: visible;
    min-height: 56px;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 823px) {
    .nav {
        float: right;
    }
    .logo {
    float: left;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 822px) {
    body .nav .nav-menu li a {
        margin-top: 4px;
    }
    .logo img {
        max-width: 135px !important;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
    }
    .nav-outer {
        height: 21px;
    }
    .nav.yoga .nav-toggled-controls {
        top: -40px;
        margin-bottom: -36px;
    }
    .nav-clear {
        padding-top: 37px;
        margin-bottom: -15px;
    }
}
.logo img {
    max-height: 100px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #002859;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 70px 10px 50px 10px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#253688, #060729);
}
.navigation:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.nav .nav-menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px !important;
    position: relative;
}
.nav-button:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.nav .nav-toggled ul {
    display:none;
    margin:0px ;
    padding:0px ;
    position: relative;
}
.nav .nav-menu > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10000000000;
    top: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    background: #505E67;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
    display: none;    
}
.nav.yoga .nav-menu > li > ul a {
    padding: 11px 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: none;
}
.nav .nav-menu > li > ul  li {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav .nav-menu > li > ul > li  ul {
    position: absolute;
    right: -100%;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
    background: #505E67;
}
.nav .nav-menu > li > ul > li  ul a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.nav ul {
    overflow: visible;
}
.has-children {
    position: relative;
}
.has-children:after {
    content: '+';
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.has-children:hover:after {
    content: '-';
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
}
body .nav .nav-menu li a {
    padding: 15px 30px;
}
.clicker {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 30000;
}
.nav-clear {
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 67px;
}
/*--- End Navigation Style --*/
/*--------------------MEDIA!!!---------------*/
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #banner-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        -ms-overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .nav-menu {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: what does your html look like?

Comment: Please post your full HTML and CSS code.

Comment: Didn't see any problem with bootstrap , just fix the `max-height: 100px;` in your `.logo img` styles and give it a larger value .

Comment: @Pete i tried doing that but no changes

Answer (score 0):

add your bootstrap css at the top

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Sabreen's Seafood Market &amp; Restaurant</title>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      rel="stylesheet" >
    <link href="css/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/seafood-favicon.png"/>

</head>
```

Comment: try replacing this .logo img {
    max-width: 130px;
    max-height: 100px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #002859;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#253688, #060729);
}

Answer (score 0):

As you have not posted the full code here , I can suggest you to do this
List out all the properties that are overlapping when you add the external CSS File.

for suppose i have a `<div class="firstDiv" id="firstDivId"></div>`

1.Overwrite the properties which are affecting using `!important` property.

In file1 i have

```
.firstDiv{
width:33%;
}
```

which is overridden by bootstrap css

```
.firstDiv{
width:100%;
}
```

In file1 you update the property using !important

```
.firstDiv{
width:33%!important;
}
```

2.download the css file , attach to your project then update the bootstrap.css file with `:not` selector

In bootstrap.css property should be like

```
.firstDiv:not('#firstDivId'){
    width:33%;
    }
```

Hope this may help you.